# Cannot Build Docker Image with Angular 9 - Simple App

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

I have followed a very simple YouTube video on how to dockerize a very simple Angular 9 app.

I built the angular 9 app by typing in "ng new angular-docker".  Answered no to routing and chose CSS.  A picture of the source files is shown at the bottom.

I then created a Dockerfile at the main level of the app. Added the following code to the Dockerfile.  I have tried different version of node and nginx in the Dockerfile to no luck.

```
# stage 1 get any base dockerhub images
FROM node:12.2.0 AS builder

# here I build a base working directory "inside the image!" as /app
WORKDIR /app

# this copy will copy all files from the ANGULAR-DOCKER folder to the /app directory in the image.
COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

#STAGE 2
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/angular-docker /usr/share/nginx/html
```

When I try and build the image from the Visual Studio Code palette, I get the following errors:

```
> Executing task: docker build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t angulardocker:latest "." <

[+] Building 1.8s (7/12)
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:1.15.8-alpine                                                                                                      1.1s 
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12.2.0                                                                                                              1.0s 
 => ERROR [builder 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:12.2.0                                                                                                                        0.7s 
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:12.2.0                                                                                                                                      0.7s 
 => CANCELED [stage-1 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:1.15.8-alpine                                                                                                             0.7s 
 => => resolve docker.io/library/nginx:1.15.8-alpine                                                                                                                              0.7s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:1.15.8-alpine:
------
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12.2.0:
------
------
 > [builder 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:12.2.0:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to load cache key: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command docker build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t angulardocker:latest "."" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  I had changed my Docker ID out on docker and somehow this messed things up.  I tried to delete my old docker to make a more "user friendly" ID.  Once I logged out of my defunct Docker account and reran the build, everything worked fine.